# K-medoids/PAM - Dissimilarity Matrix

Tags: clustering, k-medoids

Just wondered if someone could provide some clarity on whether it is suitable to use partitioning around medoids (PAM) on a dataset that has not been transformed into a dissimilarity matrix?

For example, suppose I wanted to use PAM for integer-based data. Would PAM be suitable in this context, or would it need transformed into a dissimilarity matrix?

My intuition is no. But a lot of content online uses PAM on a dissimilarity matrix, yet perhaps this is only necessary with mixed data?

Would appreciate help and feedback

Comment: By the definition of medoid, it is most easily identified from distance matrix. So why don't you want to compute the matrix first?

Comment: Hi @ttnphns. Thanks for your response. I've found that PAM can take a prohibitively long time to run on such a large distance matrix. And while CLARA is a nice protocol for overcoming this inefficiency, it is not always suitable. For example, with the consensus clustering approach here, only PAM is available. https://jokergoo.github.io/cola_vignettes/cola.html#toc_3

Comment: try to search locally, "user:7828 pam medoid clustering". Maybe you are lucky to come across something valuable